# Delegate link in NSTextView causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS when typing

Tags: cocoa, delegates, exc-bad-access, nstextview

I have a subclass of NSViewController conforming to NSTextViewDelegate protocol and whose view is a subclass of NSView (obviously). I have an NSTextField text box on the nib and my subclass of NSViewController was its delegate. When I try to type in the text box it was throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS, but when I removed the delegate link then I could type just fine. I wasn't handling any events yet, I just had the link. I've poked around similar threads but I think I'm still to n00bish to understanding how to work their solutions into my specific problem. I will need to have a delegate for my textview. How can I fix this?

Comment: `NSViewController` with `iOS` tag, remove `iOS` tag and use `cocoa` tag

Comment: Are you using any delegates function of `NSTextField`?

Comment: I wasn't at first, but when I did try to use `controlTextDidChange` the same thing happened.

Comment: Did u connect delegate of the nstextfield  outlet to files owner?

Comment: Yes, it is connected.

Comment: Does it matter that I'm creating my custom view controller programmatically and adding its view as a subview to a view on my app delegate window?

Comment: VieController programatically?? ViewController has xib ..

Comment: Does your viewController confirms to `NSTextFieldDelegate` ?

Comment: If I "Add New File" and create a subclass of NSViewController Xcode gives me a xib of the same filename as the view controller I just created. I added `<NSTextFieldDelegate>` to the `@interface` line in the .h file so that it would conform. Additional info: whenever I leave the body of the `controlTextDidChange` method blank, I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, but if I put `NSLog(@"sometexthere");` in the method body then it gripes about an unrecognized selector on my view controller, but I have the method declared in my .h and implemented in my .m file. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS is mainly due to bad memory handling. Have u used any property which retain counts increases.

Comment: I'm using ARC, so I don't think I can manually call retain and release methods, but maybe I do need a strong property somewhere. Does my using ARC make a difference?

Comment: All the IBOutlets should have weak property

Comment: Thanks. Giving them all weak properties didn't work. I tried adding a textview to my main nib and setting its delegate to my app delegate and everything works fine. Think it might have something to do with my custom view controller's view being added "programmatically". I'll try to narrow down the minimal code to generate the error and post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Victory is mine!

This was the issue, in the best way I know how to describe it:

In my AppDelegate.m file I would instantiate `myCustomViewController` and add its view as a subview to the main view of my window, like such:

```
myCustomViewController *myCustomVC = [[myCustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName...];
[self.view addSubview:myCustomVC.view];
```

but I wasn't retaining myCustomViewController so when the method containing this code returned `myCustomVC` was cleaned up. Later, when I went to type in the textBox associated with `myCustomVC`'s subview, it was sending the delegate message to the memory address of `myCustomVC` which had since been deallocated.

The solution was to drop a ViewController object into my main xib and hook it to a corresponding property on file's owner.